# What is the value of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin \left(\frac 1x\right)}{x^\alpha}$?

Tags: limits

Wolfram tells me that for any $\alpha \ge 1$ (I tried up to $\alpha = 10^8$).
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac {\sin \left(\frac 1x\right)}{x^\alpha} < \infty$$ 
How can I show that this is true?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should be $\alpha<0$!

Comment: There's no way this converges for $\alpha\geq 0$...

Comment: Look at the plot that wolframalpha makes. It clearly shows something fishy is going on around 0. If you try a small $\alpha$ (1 or 2) you clearly see the mess that is going on around 0...

Comment: I include the plot here too. It only shows the imaginary part.

Comment: Have you seen my Comment?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes. I know that for $\alpha <0$ this converges automatically. However, I find it strange that wolfram thinks that for $\alpha >0$, the limit is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Function $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded as $x\rightarrow0$, while $x^{-\alpha} \rightarrow 0$ for $\alpha<0$. As a result, the limit of their product is $0$ as well.

Comment: The limit in the question is for $x\to 0$...

Comment: @bartgol: my bad.